# How to avoid poll() retreiving same message if commitSync() is not called

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm a bit confused about poll() expected behavior. In my app, if the processLogic() works, then I should commit manually the offset so when the next poll() is called I do receive the new messages.

Problem occurs when processLogic() throws an error. I set the consumer to seek to the offset failed during processing. On next poll(), it again receives the same message.(correct behavior as I ordered consumer to manually reset the offset to that position)Imagine it works fine and also doCommitSync() is called.

The unexpected behavior occurs in the following poll(). It should take the new messages, but it still retrieve the last message, which leads to call again to the processLogic() function and doCommitSync(). It also throws the following error during doCommitSync():

> Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

My consumer config:

```
enable.auto.commit=false

isolation.level=read_committed

auto.offset.reset=latest

public void runConsumer() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(this::shutdown));

    try {
      consumer.subscribe(topics);

      while (!closed.get()) {

        processedStatus.set(false);

        final ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumedRecords = consumer.poll(numRecords);
        if (!consumedRecords.isEmpty()) {
          StreamSupport.stream(consumedRecords.spliterator(), false)
            .map(ConsumerRecord::value)
            .forEach(record -> {
              try {
                processLogic(); //do some logic which can fail
                processedStatus.set(true);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error applying action: " + record.getUuid(), e);
              }
              if (processedStatus.get()) {
                doCommitSync();
              } else {
                consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(recordTopic, recordPartition), recordOffset);
              }
            });
        }
      }
    } catch (WakeupException e) {
      logger.error("Kafka Consumer wakeup exception");
    } finally {
      alertConsumer.close();
      shutdownLatch.countDown();
    }
```

Comment: First poll(...) after throwing an Exception in processLogic, returns same records as previously and next poll after reprocessing same records properly also returns the same list of records. Do I understand it properly?

Comment: is doCommitSync(...) call only `KafkaConsumer::commitSync(...)`?

Comment: @wardziniak Yes. I expected to return only new messages as poll() is called again.

Comment: @wardziniak Not at all. It calls commitSync and handle a possible WakeupException or a CommitFailedException

Comment: I think calling KafkaConsumer::commitSync or KafkaConsumer:: seek after each message is not good behaviour. Suppose your topic has one partition and you  get 5 message in KafkaConsumer::pool and 3 message throw exception and you call KafkaConsumer:: seek(... offset =3) and then 4 message throw exception then your program call KafkaConsumer:: seek(... offset =4), so you will not start from offset 3